# How can I get to know that specific product is managed by Cdiscount (FBC) using Marketplace API of Cdiscount?

Tags: api

I'm using Marketplace API. I have all products and its offer. I just want to identify that which offers are managed by FBC. I have read all documentation of cdiscount API but did not find any way from that we can identify that specific offer is managed by Cdiscount or not.

Let me explain you via example, I'm currently working on integration stuff. Now, Our system is partially integrated with cdiscount. In which we have all ours products, offers, sales and etc.

Now, I have a case that I want to update the stock of specific offer by calling API (SubmitOfferPackage). As I know that I can not update the inventory of that product which is handled or managed by Cdiscount. So, I want to update inventory of all product that was managed/handled by me.

I'm using **GetOfferListPaginated** API to get all offers. There is no parameter in response message to identify that specific offer is managed by Cdiscount or not.

Any help would be much appreciated